# How to make a window transparent while moving it

Tags: window

I want to make my window transparent while `moving` it from one place to another on the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from [**CompizConfig Settings Manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/):

[image: move window]

Comment: How can this be done in Ubuntu 18.04?